# Beam bytecode instructions

Tags: erlang, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

Hey guys I have a question about beam the file format bytecode.

What are {label,1} and {line,1} for instructions?

And has anybody a good website/sheet where I can read about reversing beam files?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Erlang's [`compile` module documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html):

> Notice that the format of assembler files is not documented, and can change between releases.

That said, the `label` instruction marks a location for branching and calling purposes, and the `line` instruction provides source location and line number information.

You might want to investigate the [Abstract Format documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/absform.html).

Comment: Okey, thank you. Another question: Do you have an idea how I can convert bytecode to a .beam file, or run the manipulated bytecode somehow?

Comment: @QDA: are you asking how to compile assembler to beam? Just store the assembler code in a `.S` file and use `erlc` to compile it to a `.beam` file.

Comment: yes exactly. I decompiled the beamfile with file:write_file("/tmp/my_beamfile_disasm", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [beam_disasm:file(my_beamfile)])).  Afterwards I tried what you said: erlc my_beamfile_disasm.S but I got an error. The crash reason erlc prints out is: crash reason: badarg. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That won't work, since `beam_disasm:file/1` returns a `#beam_file` record containing module name, exports, attributes, compilation info, and code, and that record doesn't match the format of a `.S` file. You might instead have a look at [`beam_lib`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html) and see how to extract abstract format from a beam file.

Comment: Do I need debug information to use beam_lib to get a .S file?

Comment: Yes, you need debug info to ensure the beam file has the abstract code chunk. In general I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish, so it's hard to give you advice, but I've mentioned abstract format because it's documented and easier to manipulate programmatically than assembler.

Comment: I don't have any debug info :/ Well I have a .beam file from where I need to extract a keyword. (As an exercise) If I decompile the file like I wrote above I can see the strings which the program prints and also some other strings which I dont know how they are used. So I wanted to change some bytecode in order to check out how the program reacts to it.

Comment: You can try `{beam_file,Mod,Exp,Attr,Info,Code} = beam_disasm:file("yourfile.beam").` followed by `beam_listing:module(user, {Mod,Exp,Attr,Code,NumLabels}).` where `NumLabels` is the number of labels found in `Code`. This will print the module in `.S` format to the `user` stream. You could count the labels using something like this function: `lc([], Acc) -> Acc; lc(label,Acc) -> Acc+1; lc([H|T],Acc) -> lc(T, lc(H,Acc)); lc(Tuple, Acc) when is_tuple(Tuple) -> lists:foldl(fun(X,A) -> lc(X,A) end, Acc, tuple_to_list(Tuple)); lc(_,Acc) -> Acc.` Call it like this: `NumLabels = lc(Code,0).`

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again, but if I copy the your label count function into erl I get an error message: * 1: syntax error before: '->'.

Comment: That's meant to be a compiled function. For `erl` it would be: `Count = fun Count([], Acc) -> Acc; Count(label,Acc) -> Acc+1; Count([H|T],Acc) -> Count(T, Count(H,Acc)); Count(Tuple, Acc) when is_tuple(Tuple) -> lists:foldl(fun(X,A) -> Count(X,A) end, Acc, tuple_to_list(Tuple)); Count(_,Acc) -> Acc end.` To call it: `NumLabels = Count(Code,0).`